# TypeScript require both parameters or neither

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to define a function that requires either both conditional parameters be provided, or neither? For example:

```js
function greet(firstName?: string, lastName?: string) {
  if (fistName && lastName) console.log(`Hello, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`)
  else console.log('Hello, World!')
}

greet('John', 'Doe') // Hello, John Doe!
greet() // Hello, World!
greet('John') // Invalid
```

I realize I could just use object destructuring, create two methods, or add more if statements, but I'm curious to see if this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overloading for the function's type:

```
type Greet = {
     (firstName: string, lastName: string): void;
     (): void;
};
const greet: Greet = (firstName?: string, lastName?: string) => {
  if (firstName && lastName) console.log(`Hello, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`)
  else console.log('Hello, World!')
};

greet('John', 'Doe'); // Hello, John Doe!
greet(); // Hello, World!
greet('John'); // Invalid
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gThCwoF4oG8BQUc4BQBmAlnAM7AByAhgLYQBcU5cRAdgOYA0UANledTqNmbdgEpGANwD2RACYBubLih4JUGfKUBfJQGNprclHYIkjeImRpCJAbQgB+YcBYdufe3WdNXosagAfBjKRASqxGSUDlAAZLG8-NF0AQZG0jwQAHQ80ux4AAYAEhA8udwAJOiRXhDaUFWeyXUAhAViyqWk0GmkGdm5+QDkJWXS3ADq0nA8ci1DHbqYmKZWeEMAUtIAFqxD3EMAItIQCwpQAPQXUKPlUFu7UMcQLStmwGrnVzeld1Mzczea02Oz2Yi+1wAkqxJFQePIgA)

Still, it's a bit repetitive and somewhat ugly. While doable, I'd prefer using separate functions when possible.

A similar approach, using an object instead of separate parameters:

```
type GreetParam = {
     firstName: string;
     lastName: string;
};
const greet = (param?: GreetParam) => {
  if (param) console.log(`Hello, ${param.firstName} ${param.lastName}!`)
  else console.log('Hello, World!')
};

greet({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }); // Hello, John Doe!
greet(); // Hello, World!
greet({ firstName: 'John' }); // Invalid
greet({}); // Invalid
```

Comment: just an add on:

You can define an overload like this:

```
function greet(firstName: string, secondName: string) : void;
function greet(): void;
function greet(firstName?, secondName?) {
    // implementation
}
```